# Conditional histogram in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, histogram, subset

I used the following commands to make a histogram of one variable in my dataframe. How Do I make a histogram of the same variable, but only for rows where the value is bigger than 0.8 (if the range of values is 0 to 1.0)?

```
library('ggplot2')
qplot(df$var,
               geom="histogram",
               binwidth = 5,  
               main = "var Distribution", 
               xlab = "VAR",  
               fill=I("green"), 
               col=I("blue"), 
               alpha=I(.2),
               xlim=c(0,1.0))
```

Comment: I think `df[df$var>0.8, var]` should work, pass it as the first argument in place of `df$var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to subset the frame:

Create your plot with

```
df[df$var>0.8,]
```

rather than `df`

or alternatively, assign it to another variable

```
df2 = df[df$var>0.8,]
```

and then create the plot.